# How can I run unit test script in cakephp shell?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

In composer.json file php unit is added

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
```

I am just trying to run a test script in cmd

In project folder I have given command

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Getting below result

[image]

How I will run test script using php unit in cakephp application ? My cakephp version : 4.x

Comment: Always use a tool like http://devilbox.org/ - it will give you more "Linux native" ways to work on a WinOS machine, making it much easier on so many levels. Never directly execute code here, especially if you plan to deploy on a Linux machine anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In windows you have to write the command by back slash not by forward slash.

```
project>vendor\bin\phpunit
```